# How to remove duplicate rows and get percentage value of 3 most popular elements in column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
A  B
x  q
x  q
x  k
y  w
y  h
y  w
z  e
z  e
z  e
z  c
```

How can i achieve something like that (the structure of the below dataframe is probably not correct):

```
A          B
x   (66% q) (33% k) 
y   (66% w) (33% h)
z   (75% e) (25% c)
```

---

Could someone help me with this? I am python beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df['A'],df['B'],normalize='index')
Out[352]: 
B     c     e         h         k         q         w
A                                                    
x  0.00  0.00  0.000000  0.333333  0.666667  0.000000
y  0.00  0.00  0.333333  0.000000  0.000000  0.666667
z  0.25  0.75  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
```

Comment: Perfect! Thx boss!

Comment: @Kasangras could be done in a more compact way

Answer (score 1):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"A":["x","x","x","y","y","y"],"B":["q","q","k","w","h","w"]})

regrouped = data.groupby(["A","B"],as_index=False)["B"].size()
regrouped / regrouped.groupby("A").sum()

# output
A  B
x  k    0.333333
   q    0.666667
y  h    0.333333
   w    0.666667
dtype: float64
```

Comment: @kasangras i provided a different data but if u apply it to ur data it works

Answer (score 0):

This will go close to your needs you can adjust things like you:

```
df.value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).reset_index()
```

Comment: I have that error:`*** AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'`